# Algebraic truth values in a set

Tags: logic

How do I calculate the truth value for the following statement?

$$\forall x \in \mathbb Z\forall y \in \mathbb Z(x^2|(y+1)), $$

where $b|a $ means "$a$ is divisible by $b$".

Additionally, what does the following expression in 
$$\forall x \in \mathbb Z \exists y \in \mathbb Z(x^2|(y+1))$$

I do not want solutions, I want to know how to solve these kinds of problems. Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand what the statements "$\forall x \in \mathbb Z\forall y \in \mathbb Z(x^2|(y+1))$" and "$\forall x \in \mathbb Z \exists y \in \mathbb Z(x^2|(y+1))$" mean?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, I understand however I don't understand how $(y+1)$ is divisible by $x^2$.

Comment: Well, for some $x, y$ that statement is true - e.g. if $y=8$ and $x=3$ - and for other $x,y$ it's false - e.g. if $y=8$ and $x=24$. Do you see how this relates to the sentences you're looking at?

Comment: @NoahSchweber So for all the questions do I just provide valid examples and prove it true or false?

Comment: Well, an *example* isn't enough to prove a statement *true*, just to prove it *false*. You need to figure out whether each statement is true or false; maybe this involves finding a counterexample, or maybe this involves finding a proof that the statement is actually correct.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Could you please provide an example with a similar statement (not with my question)?

Comment: Well, to prove "$\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}\exists y\in\mathbb{Z}(y>x)$", we could argue as follows: given an arbitrary $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $y=x+1$. Then $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y>x$. Does this help?